# Looping through nested modules

Tags: ruby, loops, module, enums, each

I created a module structure to hold static data which I didn't want to store in a database. Something like this:

```
module Vixen
  module Cateories
    module Amazon
      module THREE_D_PRINTED_PRODUCTS
        REFERAL_FEE_PERCENTAGE = .12
        MINIMUM_REFERAL_FEE = 0
        NAME = '3D Printed Products'
      end
      module AMAZON_DEVICE_ACCESSORIES
        REFERAL_FEE_PERCENTAGE = .25
        MINIMUM_REFERAL_FEE = 0
        NAME = 'Amazon Device Accessories'
      end
      module AMAZON_KINDLE
        REFERAL_FEE_PERCENTAGE = .15
        MINIMUM_REFERAL_FEE = 0
        NAME = 'Amazon Kindle'
      end
      module AUTOMOTIVE_AND_POWERSPORTS
        REFERAL_FEE_PERCENTAGE = .12
        MINIMUM_REFERAL_FEE = 1.00
        NAME = 'Amazon Kindle'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to select elements under the modules. Is it possible to loop each module as such:

```
Vixen::Cateories::Amazon.each { | category | print category::NAME }
```

I know this code doesn't work as is.

Comment: Storing data as constants in nested modules is a clever idea, but it's also too clever by half. A single hash with nested hashes in it would be easier to manipulate and iterate over, and as the benefit of being something you can read in from a simple YAML or JSON configuration file in the future. Constants are intended to be private to the module or class that defines them, not shared arbitrarily. That creates a mess of binding concerns and limits your ability to refactor.

Comment: You say you "don't want to store this in a database" which might be a reasonable concern today, but that may not hold true in the future. I can see this file growing from four simple things into dozens, hundreds of things, some of which need to have their values computed based on others or conditions. Then you've painted yourself into a corner.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, consider selecting it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is probably what you are trying to do:

```
Vixen::Cateories::Amazon.constants.each do
  |category| print Vixen::Cateories::Amazon.const_get("#{category}::NAME")
end
```